# Unity3d - Best way to save a lot of Vector3 in a collection?

Tags: performance, loops, grid, unity-game-engine

I am trying to save block positions in any kind of collection. For example, if I have a grid of 16*16 blocks, I need to save 256 block positions. I could just use an array or a list right? No problem here.

But what when I have a grid of grids, like a 10x10 grid of grids. So suddenly I need to save 10x10x256 blocks. I currently save the blocks in every grid, so every grid keeps track of it's own blocks. Also no problem here (yet).

The problem actually is that I need to iterate over all those grids to check if a grid has an adjunctive grid. This results in enormous looping times.

I was wondering if there is some kind of way to reduce this, or do this better.
I was thinking of using the position of these blocks as the index in the collection, but for example using a multidimensional array gives a lot out of bounds errors, so somehow I can't use that.

Comment: what you could do is make a small script for ever grid of grids and then in that script find an empty gameobject with another script and when one of those grids become adjunctive however you are figuring that get the script from the empty game object and register the grid into that script

Comment: if im understanding this correctly

Comment: Well, I already have a lists of all the grid items. And each grid item has a list of all the blocks within them. However, when having tons of grid items, with each grid item tons of blocks to iterate through, the process gets very slow. I was wondering how this process could be improved performance wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you may need this
I stored each GameObject in Array of Gameobject
YOu may not get an Exception here

```
    GameObject[,] ArrayOfGameObjects = new GameObject[10, 10];       
    public void spawnGrid ()
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                        for (int x = 0; x <10; x++) {

                        ArrayOfGameObjects[x,y] = Instantiate (YourPrefabGameObject, new Vector3 (x, y, 0),Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;   

                        }
                    }
                }

    public CheckAdjOf (GameObject gameObj)
            {

                if (gameObj == null)
                {
                     //Do your stuff if its null
                     //for example break, return 
                    }

                int x = (int)gameObj.transform.position.x;
                int y = (int)gameObj.transform.position.y;

                GameObject Left,Right,Up,Down;      

                if (x < mArray.GetUpperBound (0))       
                Right = ArrayOfGameObjects [x + 1, y] == 0);

                if (x > 0)  
                Left = ArrayOfGameObjects [x - 1, y] == 0);


                if (y < mArray.GetUpperBound (0))
                Up = ArrayOfGameObjects [x, y + 1] == 0);

                if (y > 0)
                Down = ArrayOfGameObjects [x, y - 1] == 0);

                // you can also find diagonal GameObjects 
                // do your stuff after you getting all adjunctive grid/block 

            }
```

Comment: Yes, I understand and already have pretty much this, but when having tons of lists with each list tons of items to iterate through, the process gets very slow. I was wondering how this process could be improved performance wise.

Comment: I managed to get something working that is pretty much like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to check if part of a grid is within another? If not, disregard ;)

If so, you could optimize things by creating [bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) for each of the grids. Each grid could have a collider and you could perform checks for the individual blocks only when a collision happens between two grids.

This should eliminate unnecessary loop through distant grids. You should be able to grow the bounds of a grid by using [Bounds.Encapsulate](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/Bounds.Encapsulate.html) when you add a new block.

hth.

Comment: I didnt think of this approach. Thanks, I'll look into it